# Uploading image using java HttpURLConnection (Rest service)

Tags: file-upload, image

we are trying to post an image to a sharepoint 2013 object library. We only get

System.ArgumentNullException
no value for parameter '{0}'
Parametername: parameters.Url

from the server. Can anybody help? Here is the code:

Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());

```
    String digest = requestDigest();

    URL urlPost = new URL(
            "http://myCompSite/websites/kraft/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/websites/kraft/DAT/Kapitel%201/Unterkapitel%201')/Files/add");

    File file = new File("C:\\testDMA\\Bild.jpg");

    byte[] fileAsByteArray = generateByteArray(file);
    byte[] base64ByteArrayg64 = Base64.encodeBase64(fileAsByteArray);
    String base64String = Base64.encodeBase64String(fileAsByteArray);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlPost.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("X-RequestDigest", digest);

    String body;
    body = "{'d':{'parameters':{'__metadata':{'type':'SP.FileCreationInformation'},'contentStream':'WFT per Minute','override':true,'url':'Johnny.txt'}}}";


    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
            conn.getOutputStream());

    writer.write(body);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```